# how to get updated docs SharePoint 2019 rest

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

is there a way to retrieve updated documents from a library. Instead of setting the alert in the UI we want to use the REST api to get a call of all updated docs. I saw GetChanges()...is that the way to go?
Thank you
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply calling the `items` API for a given library, sorted by `Modified desc`, will get you all the documents sorted with the most recently modified first, and the oldest at the end.  By specifying `$top`, you can limit to a specific number of recently modified documents.  The following will get you the ten most recently modified documents from "NameOfYourLibrary":

`https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('NameOfYourLibrary')/items?$top=10&$orderby=Modified desc`

Or if you want to find all documents modified since a particular date, then remove the `$top` parameter and use a filter instead.  The following finds all the documents in "NameOfYourLibrary" modified since January 1, 2020:

`https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('NameOfYourLibrary')/items?$orderby=Modified desc&$filter=Modified gt datetime'2020-01-01T00:00:00'`